# How to write unit test for a php function that executes stored procedure?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, stored-procedures, phpunit

```
public function get(): array
    {

        $val = [
            '@a' =>  $this->c,
            '@b'   => (int)$this->issucess
        ];
        try {
            return $this->db->Execute($this->spName, $val);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
           
        }
    }
```

How do I write a unit test for such functions which are executing stored procedure while returning in PHP? Is there any example for it in `PHPUnit`?

Answer (score 0):

If you test **FUNCTION, NOT PROCEDURE** - create db mock

```
$testParams = [
  '@a' => 'value',
  '@b' => 'value'
];
//stub procedure results
$testProcedureResult = [];
$dbMock = Mockery::mock(Database::class);
$dbMock->method('Execute')
  ->once()
  ->with('procedure', $testParams)
  ->willReturn($testProcedureResult);

$service = new YourTestedClass($dbMock);
//other service configuration..
$this->assertSame($testProcedureResult, $service->get());
```